# ICL3232 and SN75C3232 difference

Tags: microcontroller, uart, embedded, rs232, hardware

I'm using ICL3232EIV-16Z-T in one of my projects for UART communication. As per the datasheet, the max speed is 500Kbps. But I've tested this IC for baud rate up to 921600 and there is no data loss. Also, I've tested with SN75C3232PWR which offers the max speed 1Mbps. Also, it is tested at 921600 baud rate and there is no data loss observed.

In both cases, the time taken remains the same.

Kindly suggest which is the better IC among these two and What is the advantage over the other?

Comment: Never use a higher baudrate than in the datasheet mentioned!!

Comment: What means: better? Is enough or not.

Comment: [ICL3232](https://www.renesas.com/sg/en/www/doc/datasheet/icl3221e-22e-23e-32e-41e-43e.pdf) [SN75C3232](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65c3232.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [ICL3232](https://www.renesas.com/sg/en/www/doc/datasheet/icl3221e-22e-23e-32e-41e-43e.pdf) datasheet we see:-

> Maximum Data Rate RL = 3kΩ, CL = 1000pF, min 250 typ 500 kbps

and in the [SN75C3232](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65c3232.pdf) datasheet:-

> Maximum data rate RL = 3 kΩ CL = 1000 pF min 250 kbit/s

So it seems there isn't much difference between them.

The SN75C3232 also specifies a minimum of 1000 Kbps with a supply voltage of 4.5 to 5.5 V, so if you are running it from 5V the SN75C3232 is guaranteed to meet your requirements (the ICL3232 may do as well, but you can't complain if doesn't).